# How does the space station rotate, if at all?

Tags: thermal-control, attitude

I know the station's solar panels rotate to track the sun (and also rotate to be in-line with the station for lower drag on night passes), but how does the station itself rotate? I imagine it has to rotate for thermal management issues, or maybe not? I also believe it rotates for docking/supply ship approach, but I'm mostly interested in how it rotates for thermal management. Which axis? What's the rotation rate?

Comment: Just a quick note that some might find interesting or we get new questions about it, that the rotation of ISS solar panels isn't exactly intuitive since they're double-sided and also capable of generating electric charge from sunlight reflected off the Earth's albedo. And since they're not massless also apply torque on the station's body when rotating, which has to be canceled out.

Comment: During assembly when there were fewer solar panels, there were several different attitudes held to maximize power output.  They are not generally used today.  Real time information about the attitude systems is here: http://spacestationlive.jsc.nasa.gov/displays/adcoDisplay1.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of the time (when it's not maneuvering for experiments and/or visiting vehicles) the ISS maintains a "fixed" attitude in the noninertial Local Vertical, Local Horizontal [reference frame](http://www.asi.org/adb/04/02/00/iss-coordinate-systems.pdf).  This means that it rotates about the Y body axis (the ["port / starboard" axis](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/multimedia/iss_labs_guide.html)) at a rate of one revolution per orbit, about 0.067 degrees per second.

For easier reference, here's the International Space Station’s coordinate system (image credit: [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/multimedia/iss_labs_guide.html)):

[image]

Comment: it's incredibly appalling that they chose the x-axis as forward!  as any game engineer will tell you, z is forward!  :O

Comment: @Fattie As far as I know, in math and physics, the z-coordinate is the up-coordinate most of the time. But I also did some game programming and seen the other convention. But if I am right, OpenGL and DirectX were also different, one uses a right-handed, the other a left-handed coordinate system.

Comment: @StefanH - please note that I only mentioned *Game Development* humorously here on the Space site.  So it's only a side issue.  However, just to clarify I can absolutely, definitely, positively assure anyone reading that in all of game development, "z is forward" - no exceptions.  (For example, it's a common thing that you hire a 3D studio or artist to build some component, character, etc, and they forget to do it in z-forward, so you have 'em redo it!)  Regarding *handedness* as you say it annoyingly varies in different apps/ides/engines!!!!!

Comment: (You can find humorous rants from me about the variation-in-handedness online!  :)

Comment: @Fattie If the z-forward convention is done wrongly by some artist, I guess it should not pose much trouble to write a script interchanging, or flipping, coordinates. Anyway, just a side issue for sure here :)

Comment: Hi @StefanH , yes FTR that's very wrong.  It's absolutely essential that components are built z-forward!!!  (It would be a bit like saying, "when programming, it's not a big deal if you have the occasional crash or use globals inappropriately here or there"  :) :)  )  cheers, happy new year

Comment: @Fattie Mhh, in the most simple case, if $x$ and $z$ are switched, would not multiplying every point by the transformation matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ fix it? Similarly, every coordinate system could be transformed that way to any other, what is the problem? Btw, happy new year :)

Comment: hi @StefanH , say one of my clients is paying 1 or 2 million dollars to build a game, and my company is in charge of seeing the money is spent properly.  Say one of the art studios is so stupid they don't know that Z is forward in games.  Do you think applying a hack would be a good solution?  (I ask rhetorically!)  Software engineering from bottom to top is about having absolutely solid, reliable, pipelines .. dozens of folks along the way (sometimes a hundred) have to work with things like models and code components. Doing things wrong is a complete non-starter.

Comment: lol, BTW I don't mean to sound "grumpy", but my job is keeping large projects in order, and if it wasn't illegal I'd Kill people who diverge from good operating principles  :)  note that for example of the dozens of people mentioned, you and I would know about matrix transforms and quaternions. the other 20 wouldn't have a clue what is going on; some would be producers, some testers, some animators etc - it's just a non-starter to add to a pipeline items that are incorrect.

Comment: @Fattie Got it, in the bigger picture surely better to do it right from the start. Btw, have you heard about Cyberpunk '77, I guess CD Project has some new job offers in their software quality department :)

Comment: yes, quite !  if it was only you and me and others that can do math - you'd just throw in a transform  :)  :)  lol good one